# How do you make Unit continuously look for a closer target and then re-assign to the primary target? Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Clash Royale replica kind of game and now I have some problems making my states and target assignment work properly.

As for now, I set the primary target for units, from a **PrimaryTargetList** , then using a boolean value to look for a **CloserTarget** and then set it from **GetAttackList** or if the original target is **TargetInRange** which then sets the Fighting State.

As of now, It seems that my units are walking to the primary target (the towers or castle), but act weirdly when they detect a closer target, they either walk the map around another bridge. See Screenshot1. [image: Screenshot1]
Unit number 1 was spawned where the red dot is, was going to the enemy tower (I hope), then detected Unit number 2 somewhere, and went for him around the map, instead of moving to the tower and attacking it.
What could be the problem? Am I checking for a closer target wrong? What is a correct way to look for a closer target while having a primary target as the towers?

I did so that detection range differs from original unit attack range.

```
 public bool TargetInRange()
    {   
        return (transform.position-target.transform.position).sqrMagnitude <= attackRange*attackRange;
    }
    public bool CloserTarget()
    {
        return (transform.position - target.transform.position).sqrMagnitude <= detectRange*detectRange;
    }
```

This is where my state switching happens in GameManager script. I could be missing some logic somewhere, but I kept rereading everything and it seemed normal to me.

```
        private void Update()
        {
            EntityEvents targetToPass; //ref
            EntityEvents p; //ref
            
            for (int pN = 0; pN < allEntities.Count; pN++)
            {
                p = allEntities[pN];

                switch (p.state)
                {
                    case EntityEvents.States.Idle:
                        if (p.targetType == EntityEnums.TargetType.None)
                            break;

                        bool primaryTargetFound = FindClosestInList(p.transform.position, PrimaryTargetList(p.faction, p.targetType), out targetToPass);
                        if (!targetToPass)
                        {
                            gameOver = true;
                            GameOver();
                        } //this should only happen on Game Over
                                                                    
                        if (p.entityType == EntityEnums.Type.Unit)
                        {
                        p.SetTarget(targetToPass);
                        p.SeekTower();
                        }
                        break;
                    case EntityEvents.States.SeekingTower:
                        p.CloserTarget();
                        bool closerTargetFound = FindClosestInList(p.transform.position, GetAttackList(p.faction, p.targetType), out targetToPass);
                        if(p.CloserTarget())
                        {
                            p.SetTarget(targetToPass);
                            p.SeekUnit();
                        }
                        else if(p.TargetInRange())
                            p.StartFighting();
                        break;
                    case EntityEvents.States.SeekingUnit:
                        if (p.entityType == EntityEnums.Type.Structure || p.entityType == EntityEnums.Type.Castle)
                        {
                            bool targetFound = FindClosestInList(p.transform.position,GetAttackList(p.faction, p.targetType), out targetToPass);
                            if (!targetToPass)
                            {
                                gameOver = true;
                                GameOver();
                            }
                        } //this should only happen on Game Over
                        else if (p.TargetInRange()) 
                            p.StartFighting();
                        break;

                    case EntityEvents.States.Fighting:
                        if (p.TargetInRange())
                            if (Time.time >= p.lastAttackTime + p.attackRatio)
                            {
                                p.DoDamage();
                            }
                        break;

                    case EntityEvents.States.Dead:
                        if (p.TargetInRange() == false) Debug.Log(p.name + " | is dead");
                        p.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                        RemoveEntityFromList(p);
                        Debug.Log("He's dead, he shouldn't be here");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Debug.Log("This entity has no state!");
                        break;
                }
            }
```

I use the **FindClosestInList** function to return the closes enemy unit.

```
        private bool FindClosestInList(Vector2 p, List<EntityEvents> list, out EntityEvents t)
        {
            t = null;
            bool foundTarget = false;
            float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                float sqrDistance = (p - (Vector2)list[i].transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
                if (sqrDistance < closestDistanceSqr)
                {
                    t = list[i];
                    closestDistanceSqr = sqrDistance;
                    foundTarget = true;
                }
            }
            return foundTarget;
        }
```

Comment: How does `SeekUnit()` method work?

Comment: Your logic is hard to understand especially since we don't have all the types and don't know what all your methods do ... In general I would say: Find primary target **once**, find close targets continously, if temporary target is closer than primary target (or whatever your priorities are) -> attack closer target, otherwise attack primary target

Comment: It just sets the target, which is then used to set navmesh agent destination.

`public void SetTarget(EntityEvents t)
        {
            target = t;
            t.OnDie += TargetIsDead;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign every target a corresponding TargetType-Tag, place circle colliders on the units and set the bitmap to ignore certain targets. That way you can get the list of collisions and their GameObjects and calculate the distance.

The code would be way simpler to understand for others and it could possibly solve your problem.